# for loop errors, counter defined in header file

Tags: c, for-loop, header

I wrote a simple program composed by three files (main.c, libreria_mia.c, libreria_mia.h):

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libreria_mia.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}




// libreria_mia.h
struct  numeri{
    int n[100];
};
int i;



// libreria_mia.c
#include "libreria_mia.h"
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    numeri.n[i] = 2;
}
```

The compiler gives me the following errors:

```
libreria_mia.c:5:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘for’
    5 | for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      | ^~~
libreria_mia.c:5:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘<’ token
    5 | for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      |               ^
libreria_mia.c:5:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘++’ token
    5 | for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      |                       ^~
```

How can i fix them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't have general statements outside of functions. All decent books, classes and tutorials should have told you that.

Comment: Also don't define variables in header files, because that will define the variable in all source-files where that header file is included. Only *declare* variables in the header files, and then define in a single source file.

Comment: Lastly, `numeri` is a *structure* tag, not a variable. In short it seems you have either skipped a lot of your classes or tutorials, or skipped too much of your books (or a combination). My recommendation is that you take a few steps back, and start all over from the very beginning

Comment: Hello @Someprogrammerdude what i defined in the header file? The struct numeri and the variable i are only declared...maybe i did a mistake and i didn't see it.

Comment: `int i;` is a *tentative **definition*** of the variable `i`. If there are no other definitions in the current [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) then it will be considered an actual definition. And since you have two translation units the variable `i` will be defined in both, leading to errors when you link.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++ you can't declare variables in a header file that is included in multiple files.

You have to declare variables in C file and declare extern in a header file:

As an example:

main.c

```
int i;
```

libreria_mia.h

```
extern int i;
```

then include this header file wherever you want to use the variable i.

Comment: Great clarification @Ansary

Comment: Yes you can declare variables in header files. You can even *define* variables in header file, but if the header file is included into multiple translation units that will lead to multiple-definition errors when linking. *And* you have to learn the difference between a declaration and a definition.